# Change the old style numerals of mathpazo (via tufte-latex) to lining numerals

Tags: fonts, tufte, oldstylenums, mathpazo

I am using `tufte-latex` package, which uses `mathpazo` with old style numerals.
To make figures (plots) I would like to use lining numbers. 
The problem is that the figures are converted from svg to pdf using inkscape and the numbers are not in mathmode (In math mode the numbers are lining numerals by default).

I think of two possible solutions:

a) Is there any command similar to `\oldstylenums` that does the opposite work?

b) inkscape put the text of the figure in `\smash{-22.22}` commands. Is any way, 
using sed, awk, perl,... to change that to `\smash{$-22.22}`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `tufte` classes load `mathpazo` with the `osf` option which defines `\rmdefault` as `pplj` (real small caps plus oldstyle numbers). To switch to lining numbers for the whole document, you want `pplx` (real small caps plus lining numbers).

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{pplx}

\begin{document}

0123456789

\end{document}
```

As an alternative, you may define a `\liningnums` macro to switch to `pplx` within a group. Note: the additional pair of braces is necessary to keep the font switch local.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\newcommand{\liningnums}[1]{%
    {\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont #1}}

\begin{document}

\liningnums{0123456789}

0123456789

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. For the records, finally I use the following two commands to switch back and forth with old style numerals
`\newcommand{\liningnums}{%
  \fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont%
}
\newcommand{\oldnums}{%
\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont%
}`

Comment: @zunbeltz Check my answer again - your macros are missing the additional pair of braces, which are necessary for keeping the font switch local.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I need to change the fonts globally while I create the figure. Those command do not have any arguments.