# How to make spacedallcaps increase size of numbers as well?

Tags: formatting, capitalization

When I'm using spacedallcaps it does what is suppose to do capitalizes letters and inserts spaces, but has no effect on numbers.

Is there a way to make numbers proportionally increase?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[main=english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\areaset[current]{\textwidth}{1.618034\textwidth}

\begin{document}
    \spacedallcaps{yada-1 yada} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please help us help you and provide a minimal working example (MWE) that others are able to compile in order to reproduce the problem you have.

Comment: @JasperHabicht sorry, have not realized I was using some packages for this to work. Happens when checking out projects without understanding the content.

Comment: OK, are you using PDFLaTeX or XeLaTeX to generate your PDF?

Comment: I'm using PDFLaTeX MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.5496

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation to the below answer: `classicthesis` loads the `mathpazo` package with the `osf` (old style figures) option. The following redefines the `\spacedallcaps` macro by temporarily restoring the used font as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56371/change-the-old-style-numerals-of-mathpazo-via-tufte-latex-to-lining-numerals):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[main=english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\areaset[current]{\textwidth}{1.618034\textwidth}

\let\oldspacedallcaps\spacedallcaps
\renewcommand{\spacedallcaps}[1]{{\fontfamily{pplx}\selectfont\oldspacedallcaps{#1}}}

\begin{document}
 \spacedallcaps{yada-1 yada}
\end{document}
```

Note that this answer only works if the standard font used with `classicthesis` is Palatino (from the package `mathpazo` that is loaded by default).